# Detecting optional and required properties using a generic function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How can TypeScript infer that certain function arguments are required and others optional when default values are provided?

For example, the following code:

```
type UnitType = "distance" | "area";

type ConverterParams = Record<string, UnitType>;
type Converters<P extends ConverterParams> = Record<
  string,
  (
    params: Partial<Record<P extends infer R ? keyof R : never, number>>
  ) => number
>;
type UnitConversion<P extends ConverterParams, C extends Converters<P>> = {
  readonly params: P;
  readonly converters: C;
};
type ConverterBuilderOptions<
  P extends ConverterParams,
  C extends Converters<P>
> = {
  params: P;
  converters: C;
};

const buildConverters = <P extends ConverterParams, C extends Converters<P>>({
  params,
  converters,
}: ConverterBuilderOptions<P, C>): UnitConversion<P, C> => {
  return { params, converters };
};
```

I can build the following test value

```
const testConverter = buildConverters({
  params: {
    width: "distance",
    height: "distance",
  },
  converters: {
    surface: ({ width, height = 1 }) => width || 0 * height,
    //                 ^ height: number
    //          ^ width: number | undefined
  },
});


testConverter.converters.surface({});
// No error, should require "width" because there is no default value
```

In short, right now, because all arguments are optional, all are `number | undefined`. Is there a way to detect when an argument has a default value? That is, only make `number | undefined` those with a default value, and `number` those who don't, and have them required when calling the function?

```
testConverter.converters.surface({});
// should error with missing `width` property
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I sincerely doubt this is possible; it would require multiple inference passes where currently there is one; usually you can either get [contextual typing](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of a callback param, or inference of a [generic](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument, but in order for this to work you'd need both at the same time in the same value, and TS can't usually do it (see [ms/TS#30134](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134) and [ms/TS#44999](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44999)).

Comment: Not sure how to proceed here. Would you be interested in some kind of refactoring where inference is easier (but necessarily forces you to do some things you probably think you shouldn't need to)? Or would you just like a "no, this impossible" with links to GitHub issues?  (Well, I'm sure you'd like a "yes this is possible" but I don't know who would write such an answer. I'd be interested in seeing it too!)

Comment: @jcalz I'm not yet a TS guru, so I was curious to know as well. Honestly, some TS projects really have funky type defs! For the time being, having a `Partial` is good enough, but I will keep the question here just in case someone has a different perspective on this. Thanks for trying!